# Module Title Not Showed On Joomla Custom Template

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1

I have been creating template for joomla 3.1, I was followed the instruction from joomla doc how to create it. Every thing is going fine. But, when I set module title is showed on front end, that module title is not showed. Below is snippet code of my template

```
    <?php 

defined('_JEXEC') or die( 'Restricted access' );

JLoader::import('joomla.filesystem.file');


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<jdoc:include type="head" />
</head>
<body>
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" />
<jdoc:include type="component" />
</body>
</html>
```

All module content is showed. Only the module title is not showed. Thanks for your advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jdoc statement is missing the style attribute, which is what defines the type of module chrome is used, which is what renders the module's title. See http://docs.joomla.org/Module_chrome for more details.